# display text file and update when the file contents change

Tags: bash

I want to have a window open that is just the content of the file `file.txt`. I do not care which command I use to open it, `nano, cat, vi` or whatever. I want it to update every time it changes, so if I open it in another window, edit it and save it, the file in the original window will update, kind of like `screen`. Any suggestions?

I have already tried just having it open a new `cat file.txt` command every few seconds, but it is very unreliable.

Comment: Are you working on Linux?

Comment: What is "very unreliable"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
watch cat file.txt
```

That should update when any changes occur, also try

```
man watch
```

To see what options it has so you can update the frequency of the updates.

Answer (score 8):

The low-tech solution in case `watch` is not available:

```
 while sleep 1; do tput clear; cat file.txt; done
```

(lets you easily adapt the checking interval).

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use the [inotifywait command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait --event modify file.txt; do
    tput clear
    cat file.txt
done
```

which is a modified version of **Example 2** in the man page. This has the great advantage of doing absolutely nothing until file.txt is modified. The answers suggesting polling have the problems that polling always does: it will waste time when nothing has changed, and it will fail to catch changes until the polling interval has ended.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on macOS you probably don't have `watch` installed per standard. You could go for the low-tech solution - which is elegant anyway, but you can also revert to [home-brew](https://brew.sh).

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

You might have to give it (once!) your (administration) password. After the installation finishes, you should always check the system:

`brew doctor`

There should be a message along the lines:

> Your system is ready to brew.

Now you are ready to install `watch`:

`brew install watch`

Once that is finished, you are ready for the solution by @dave-mackintosh:

`watch cat file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

### Q: How to monitor text file and print output in realtime?

### A: `tail -F logfile.txt`

Outputs the file whenever it is updated.

### A2: `watch -n 0.1 -t tail -n 3 logfile.txt`

Calling `watch -n 0.1` means that the command is being executed every 0.1 seconds. The smallest accepted update interval is 0.1. Title is suppressed by `-t`.
Every 0.1 seconds, the last three lines (`tail -n 3`) are printed.

<sub>This is not suitable for high resolution applications.</sub>